# Will Ubuntu continue working properly after a new motherboard/CPU is installed?

Tags: drivers, hardware, cpu

So, I installed the new motherboard and new CPU. Then powered on the PC. The bootstrapping went fine and all seems to work. But I have doubts. Do I need to do something?

Comment: If your new CPU is an AMD model, you could try opening the *Additional Drivers* utility to check if there is an ATI/AMD proprietary graphics driver available to be installed.

Comment: Are you experiencing any actual problems? If not, I would go with: "If it's not broken, don't fix it". If you are encountering performance problems, following @karel suggestion is a good idea.

Comment: @Aizikil Is your question for Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not unclear anymore; it's asking if anything special has to be done in Ubuntu when/after replacing a motherboard and CPU. It can be, [and is](http://askubuntu.com/a/509658/22949), well answered. We should reopen this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do much. As per comments, check for additional drivers. Though, I recommend running a SMART check on HDD if you were manipulating them in process. You would need actions if:

- You installed something from source with `-march=native`. -- reinstall it.
- You did some manual non-standart configuration to adapt to hardware -- check if it still works.
- If you had been running Gentoo you would possibly need re-emerging everything because it is attuned to CPU model. All .deb and .rpm distros are attuned to architecture subfamily, so as long as you stay within one it should just work.